# Will terminal keep executing a command after i disconnect my VNC session?

Tags: mac-osx, vnc

I established a remote session in a MacOSX (10.6.8) from my PC (Windows7) using VNC.
I initiated terminal and it is currently executing a task that will take probably 1 day before completing. Should I expect that even if I disconnect the VNC session, Terminal will keep running after I disconnect? I assume so since I used VNC just to remotely start the process but want to double check. Can anybody tell me if I am wrong?

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  This is a good question, but probably off-topic for ServerFault.  Check out the [faq] for a list of what is and isn't on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Disconnecting a VNC session does nothing to the processes that are running. In case you get disconnected for some other technical reasons, you can reconnect and continue what you were previously doing.

Just make sure that you **disconnect**, as opposed to **log out**.